# Restrict Interface Orientation in iOS 7 and iOS 8

Tags: iphone, ios7, ios8, screen-orientation, interface-orientation

I am trying to implement something where I stuck at one point.

I want some orientation restrictions as follows:

- **For iPhone 4, 4S, 5, 5S, & 6  - Portrait Only**
- **For iPhone 6 Plus             - Both Portrait & Landscape**
- **For iPad                      - Both Portrait & Landscape**

I have tried all the combination of coding. Finally I got solution for **iOS 8**

```
**(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window  // iOS 6 autorotation fix
{**


        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){

            if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector: @selector(scale)])
            {
                if(IS_IPHONE_4_AND_OLDER){

                    printf("Device Type : iPhone 4,4s ");
                    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
                }
                else if(IS_IPHONE_5){

                    printf("Device Type : iPhone 5,5S/iPod 5 ");
                    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
                }
                else if(IS_IPHONE_6){

                    printf("Device Type : iPhone 6 ");
                    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
                }
                else if(IS_IPHONE_6P){

                    printf("Device Type : iPhone 6+ ");
                    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
                }
            }
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
        }
        else{

            printf("Device Type : iPad");
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
        }
}
```

By using above code I manage for iOS 8 But it does not work in iOS 7 or less

Please help me to solve this ...

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Simple but it work very fine. IOS 7.1 and 8**

**AppDelegate.h**

```
@property () BOOL restrictRotation;
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {

if(self.restrictRotation)

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
else

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
```

}

**ViewController**

At top: To Detect Device Type

```
#define IS_IPHONE (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
#define IS_IPAD (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)

#define IS_IPHONE_5_IOS7 (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568.0f)
#define IS_IPHONE_6_IOS7 (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 667.0f)
#define IS_IPHONE_6P_IOS7 (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 736.0f)
#define IS_IPHONE_4_AND_OLDER_IOS7 (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height < 568.0f)

#define IS_IPHONE_5_IOS8 (IS_IPHONE && ([[UIScreen mainScreen] nativeBounds].size.height/[[UIScreen mainScreen] nativeScale]) == 568.0f)
#define IS_IPHONE_6_IOS8 (IS_IPHONE && ([[UIScreen mainScreen] nativeBounds].size.height/[[UIScreen mainScreen] nativeScale]) == 667.0f)
#define IS_IPHONE_6P_IOS8 (IS_IPHONE && ([[UIScreen mainScreen] nativeBounds].size.height/[[UIScreen mainScreen] nativeScale]) == 736.0f)
#define IS_IPHONE_4_AND_OLDER_IOS8 (IS_IPHONE && ([[UIScreen mainScreen] nativeBounds].size.height/[[UIScreen mainScreen] nativeScale]) < 568.0f)

#define IS_IPHONE_5 ( ( [ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] respondsToSelector: @selector( nativeBounds ) ] ) ? IS_IPHONE_5_IOS8 : IS_IPHONE_5_IOS7 )
#define IS_IPHONE_6 ( ( [ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] respondsToSelector: @selector( nativeBounds ) ] ) ? IS_IPHONE_6_IOS8 : IS_IPHONE_6_IOS7 )
#define IS_IPHONE_6P ( ( [ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] respondsToSelector: @selector( nativeBounds ) ] ) ? IS_IPHONE_6P_IOS8 : IS_IPHONE_6P_IOS7 )
#define IS_IPHONE_4_AND_OLDER ( ( [ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] respondsToSelector: @selector( nativeBounds ) ] ) ? IS_IPHONE_4_AND_OLDER_IOS8 : IS_IPHONE_4_AND_OLDER_IOS7 )
```

Then Add Function Below:

```
-(void) restrictRotation:(BOOL) restriction{

AppDelegate* appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
appDelegate.restrictRotation = restriction;}
```

**viewDidLoad**

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){

    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector: @selector(scale)])
    {
        if(IS_IPHONE_6P){

            printf("Device Type : iPhone 6+ ");
            [self restrictRotation:NO];
        }
        else{

            printf("Device Type : iPhone 6 ");
            [self restrictRotation:YES];
        }
    }
}
else{

    printf("Device Type : iPad");
    [self restrictRotation:NO];
}
```